# What is the most valuable earthly possession for a human?

Tags: riddle

> The one thing without which humans are mere vegetables.
>
> The one thing which although functional , unfortunately gets corrupted over the years and becomes a toxic version of the original, the fruit of which is seen all around the world.
>
> Tragically although man has an idea of what might be wrong, he doesn't seek or bother to do much about it.

**What is the most valuable earthly possession for a human?**

Comment: The grammar's kind of confusing to read, could you clarify, especially the first?

Comment: "The one thing without which humans just cant go on without" I'm fairly certain there are many things that are essential to life. Essentially any global resource can be fit into this riddle. This includes: The Sun, Water, Oxygen, The Earths core, Atmosphere, Food, Soil. Other solutions include: Mental health, Body, Organs. All of these degrade over time, everyone depends on these and everyone knows the importance but no full global effort has been established towards any of these

Comment: @North Please see edits , hopefully it makes sense now

Comment: Voted to reopen. I think the edits help clarify things.

Answer (score 4):

It can be

> Water or Air. As it gets polluted over time by humans and the fruit which means the result is global warming.